# How can I hide a specific div with css in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a CSS-created form that is great in all browsers, screen sizes, etc. except IE 8. It is not important enough to keep messing with it, and I want to just hide it for users of IE 8. Is there a simple CSS attribute I can add?

Comment: You could wrap it in IE8 Conditional Comments, as I'm sure the answer below will suggest, however if you share more details we may be able to help you resolve the issue in IE8 without having to hide anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using conditional comments you can simply add a line of CSS to hide whatever element you need out of the way. Something like this should work:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style>
        #id {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was unaware of conditional comments. Thank you.

Comment: @Eric No problem! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so we can close this one out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could add a class to the html if ie 8 like :

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
```

and then style it based on that.